# how to evaluate $\int \left(\hat{V}\times \frac{d^2\hat{V}}{dt^2}\right)dt$?

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals, vector-analysis

> if $\hat{V}\left(t\right)$ is a vector function of $t$, find the indefinite integral $\int \left(\hat{V}\times \frac{d^2\hat{V}}{dt^2}\right)dt$

To solve thi first i find for the integrand with matrix since it's in the form of cross product, so

$\hat{V}\times \frac{d^2\hat{V}}{dt^2}=\begin{pmatrix}\hat{i} & \hat{j} & \hat{k} \\V_x & V_y & V_z \\\frac{d^2V_x}{dt^2} & \frac{d^2V_y}{dt^2} & \frac{d^2V_z}{dt^2}\end{pmatrix}=\left(V_y\frac{d^2V_z}{dt^2}-V_z\frac{d^2V_y}{dt^2}\right)\hat{i}+\left(V_z\frac{d^2V_x}{dt^2}-V_x\frac{d^2V_z}{dt^2}\right)\hat{j}+\left(V_x\frac{d^2V_y}{dt^2}-V_y\frac{d^2V_x}{dt^2}\right)\hat{k}$

and then substitute this value into the integral, i get

$\int \left(\hat{V}\times \frac{d^2\hat{V}}{dt^2}\right)dt=\left[\int\left(V_y\frac{d^2V_z}{dt^2}\right)dt-\int\left(V_z\frac{d^2V_y}{dt^2}\right)dt\right]\hat{i}+\left[\int\left(V_z\frac{d^2V_x}{dt^2}\right)dt-\int\left(V_x\frac{d^2V_z}{dt^2}\right)dt\right]\hat{j}+\left[\int\left(V_x\frac{d^2V_y}{dt^2}\right)dt-\int\left(V_y\frac{d^2V_x}{dt^2}\right)dt\right]\hat{k}$

What should i do next? how to evaluate each of these indefinite integrals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider that

$$\frac{d}{dt} (\mathbf{v} \times\mathbf{\dot{v}} ) = \mathbf{\dot{v}} \times\mathbf{\dot{v}} +\mathbf{v} \times\mathbf{\ddot{v}} $$

What is the cross product of a vector and itself?

Comment: the cross product of a vector and itself is zero, sir. Am i right?

Comment: that is correct.

Comment: @alethiologist: yes.

Comment: so the answer would be $\int \left(\hat{V}\times \:\frac{d^2\hat{V}}{dt^2}\right)dt=\hat{V}\times \frac{d\hat{V}}{dt}+C$ ? @RonGordon

Comment: @alethiologist: yes

Comment: Awesome!! thank you so much, sir!! @RonGordon